# React native Xcode build error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using react native 0.39.2 version, after running on device using xcode 8.2.1 i am getting this error :

> Shell Script Invocation Error
>
> ../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh: line 41: cd: /Users/shafips/Documents/Projects/My: No such file or directory.

any idea.

Comment: Don't use spaces in folder names. It doesn't usually go well with crappy dev tools

Comment: MyProject is my project name. there is no space :(

Comment: Then the tools seem even more broken :/

Comment: FYI, you don't need XCode running for `run-ios` to open the simulator. And usually, it can mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove iOS and Android folders and run

```
$react-native upgrade
```

Then

```
$react-native link
```

Try running again

Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

Solved!.
Yes, Removed spaces from project folders.